# Ordenar listado con primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

Mirando la documentación, no he encontrado una opción en la que pueda ordenar por ejemplo por "name":

https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/listbox

¿Alguna opción?

Comment: Las listas se muestran en el orden que tú les pases. Ordena el array antes y se mostrará ordenado

Comment: @PabloLozano Si pero si me pasan ya el listado desordenado tengo ue hacerlo en el cliente, en angularjs era algo tan fácil como orderby, ¿existe algo parecido?

Comment: Creo que no hay algo tan directo en Angular. Si no te quieres complicar y hacerlo a mano, puedes poner la librería de [Lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) y usar su función [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy)

Comment: al final he tenido que usarl el .sort para ordenar.